# SSIS Validate a Foreach File Enumerator

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

i have a ssis project, to start with, i have a Foreach File Enumerator and inside it are multiple tasks. It works flawlessly under normal circumstances, however if there is no file present in the enumerator directory, an error occurs, the question is, how can i make a validation or some sort for it to avoid it throwing an error on runtime? thanks

img links

ssis 
http://s15.postimage.org/l41py15aj/ssis.png
error
http://s15.postimage.org/rj0qupc0b/ssiserror.png

Comment: also is there a way to check if the directory is existing? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a script task before `Foreach` loop which basically checks for files and directory .Then have a [precedence constraint](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/) to halt the package if either directory or files is not present .

Create 3 variables

```
 Name        DataType   
 Directory   String
 Files       String
 Exists      int
```

In the script task just check if the directory is present along with the files .You can modify the code if you need to even enumerate the subfolders or check if specific files are present in the folder

```
if (Directory.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::Files"].Value.ToString()))
{
if (Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables["User::Files"].Value.ToString()).Length != 0)
    {
      Dts.Variables["User::Exists"].Value = 1;
     }
            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::Exists"].Value = 0;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::Exists"].Value = 0;
        }
```

In the precedence constraint check the value for the  variable `Exists`

```
    Evaluation operation : Expression
    Expression           : @Exists==1
```

Update :

In the script task editor you need to add the variables in the `ReadOnlyVariable` section in the script tag

Comment: hi, im getting an Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the expression on the Disable of the Sql Task assert whether the a file name was valid.

I haven't got SSIS here but I'll look it up.

Comment: hi I tried to do this however since the filename variable is filled up after the foreach loop enumerator, it will always return null since the condition will begin first before the forloop right?.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware of this particular case when the error occurs and you want to handle it. What if it fails for some other unforeseen error?

Always add an **'OnError'** Event Handler.

Now, after handling your error condition using the event handler, you can choose to propogate this error to fail the task (which is the default behavior) or you can set the system variable, **Propogate**, in your 'OnError' event handler to **false**. This will allow the rest of the code after the **For Each** to continue as normal.